# GIT various history commands

Tags: git, github

A colleague and I were discussing some of the history commands within GIT but were struggling to come up with commands other than **git log** and **git diff** are there any other history commands out there that we're missing. There has to be others that we're just not thinking of. We both aggressively started doing some googling but couldn't find many other commands. Does anybody know of any others out there?

Comment: See `git help -a` to get a list of all of Git's commands.

Comment: @PeterLundgren Indeed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **git shortlog**: to summarize git log output
- **git reflog**: to examine the various changes that occured to the tip of a branch
- **git stash**: to list the various snapshots of code you've saved back in time
- **git blame**: to see when (and by whom) some piece of code has been changed
- **git filter-branch**: to rewrite the history of the repository

One can get more detail at **http://git-scm.com/docs**, where is hosted the official and comprehensive man pages that are included in the Git package itself.

Answer (score 1):

How about these commands:

```
git reflog
git shortlog
git whatchanged
```

Comment: Thanks @jh314 are there any others I would think there would be a few others out there.

Comment: @DelmonYoung One other one is `git-show`, as well as the ones nulltoken mentioned in his answer.